# In Cassandra 1.2 - CQL 3 is it possible to abort a secondary index build?

Tags: cassandra, schema, operations

Been using a 6GB dataset with each source record being ~1KB in length when I accidentally added an index on a column that I am pretty sure has a 100% cardinality.

Tried dropping the index from cqlsh but by that point the two node cluster had gone into a run away death spiral with loadavg surpassing 20 on each node and cqlsh hung on the drop command for 30 minutes.  Since this was just a test setup, I shut-down and destroyed the cluster and restarted.

This is a fairly disconcerting problem as it makes me fear a scenario where a junior developer is on a production cluster and they set an index on a similar high cardinality column.  I scanned through the documentation and looked at the options in nodetool but there didn't seem to be anything along the lines of "abort job or abort building index".

Test environment:
2x m1.xlarge EC2 instances with 2 Raid 0 ephemeral disks
Dataset was 6GB, 1KB per record.

My question in summary:  Is it possible to abort the process of building a secondary index AND or possible to stop/postpone running builds (indexing, compaction) for a later date.

Answer (score 2):

nodetool -h node_address stop index_build

See: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/references/nodetool#nodetool-stop

Comment: For some reason when I tried that during my test, it didn't actually stop the secondary index build.  Not sure if it was just how screwed up my test cluster had gotten before I tried to intercede or if there was something else broken.